# How to create an options menu like YouTube app does on android?

Tags: android, android-menu

Youtube app on android shows options menu for a video by pressing the three dots button available for every video.

I know that android-sdk provides [Contextual-Menus for list views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu), but the contextual menu will appear in the middle of the screen, and this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

[image: Three dots button that shows options menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). You can make your own like this:

```
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(
            context,
            anchorView);

    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.my_menu);

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
    popupMenu.show();
```